# Glb and Lub in a lattice diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

> Given the following lattice, what is the pair $(c \wedge e, d \vee b)?$
>
> [image: Lattice]

I know that $c \wedge e=0$.

But is $d \vee b=d$ or $d \vee b=1$? I don't really understand it.

($\wedge,\vee$ represent glb,lub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Write all the elements that are $\geq b$: $\{b,d,e,1\}$
- Write all the elements that are $\geq d$: $\{d,1\}$

What is the lowest upper bound? If you look at both sets you conclude that is the element $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Since b < d < 1, how could 1 be the ***least*** upper bound of {b,d}?

Comment: So the answer is d?

Comment: @AndreMath.  Is d an upper bound of b and d?  What other upper bounds of b and d are there?  Are any of them smaller than d?